Create entities from existing database
I have an project where I want to connect an existing database with the entities, so I can use typeorm and the auto-generated migrations.
I have created the entities in a basic form, however when I generate the migrations I get too many changes, some of the changes e.g. dropping constraints for foreign keys are recreated and it's fine as a one time thing. However, the migration is re-creating primary keys and types (by dropping them and the then immediately creating them).
enum PaymentStatus {
  INITIAL = 'INITIAL',
  CANCELLED = 'CANCELLED',
  DENIED = 'DENIED',
  PENDING = 'PENDING',
  DONE = 'DONE'
}

@Entity('payments')
export class Payment {
  @Index('payments_user_idx')
  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'id',
    type: 'varchar',
    primaryKeyConstraintName: 'payments_pkey',
    nullable: false,
  })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'partner_id', nullable: true, type: 'varchar' })
  partnerId: string | undefined;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: PaymentStatus,
    default: PaymentStatus.INITIAL,
    enumName: 'payments_status_enum',
    nullable: false,
  })
  status: PaymentStatus;
}

This is the generated migration
await queryRunner.query('DROP INDEX "public"."payments_user_idx"');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" DROP CONSTRAINT "payments_pkey"');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" DROP COLUMN "id"');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" ADD "id" character varying NOT NULL');
await queryRunner.query(
      'ALTER TABLE "payments" ADD CONSTRAINT "payments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")',
    );
await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" DROP COLUMN "partner_id"');
await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" ADD "partner_id" character varying');
await queryRunner.query(
      'ALTER TYPE "public"."payment_status" RENAME TO "payment_status_old"',
    );
await queryRunner.query(
      "CREATE TYPE \"public\".\"payments_status_enum\" AS ENUM('INITIAL', 'CANCELLED', 'DENIED', 'PENDING', 'DONE')",
    );
await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "payments" ALTER COLUMN "status" DROP DEFAULT');
await queryRunner.query(
      'ALTER TABLE "payments" ALTER COLUMN "status" TYPE "public"."payments_status_enum" USING "status"::"text"::"public"."payments_status_enum"',
    );

What am I doing wrong in the definition of the entity? Can this be fixed or is it a bug?
I'm leaning on avoiding auto-generated migrations and just go with a simple entity definition.
